# HTML/CSS - Display:inline not working

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my website. I am struggling to achieve that three pictures are shown as "display:inline", which means next to each other and not under each other.

I can't find my mistake and would welcome and hints.

```css
.trikot {
  max-width: 1050px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
.trikotset {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
#buy_button {
  background-color: #9c1737;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<section class="trikot">
  <div id="trikot1">
    <img class="trikotset" src="img/trikot.jpg">
    <button id='buy_button' type='button'>Jetzt Kaufen</button>
  </div>
  <div id="trikot2">
    <img class="trikotset" src="img/hose.jpg">
    <button id='buy_button' type='button'><a href=>Jetzt Kaufen</button>
  </div>
  <div id="trikot3">
  <img class="trikotset" src="img/traningsanzug.jpg">
  <button id='buy_button' type='button'><a href=>Jetzt Kaufen</button>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: make it display:inline-block

Comment: For starters you omitted the `</a>` twice. I edited your question with your code and placed it in a snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried display:inline-block; and it is not working. And Thank you @J08691.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would find floats much more reliable for this type of situation because I don't see you need vertical positioning.

EDIT : remember to include clearfix! Floated elements are similar to absolute, they are taken from the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

The images are inside the containers #trikot1, #trikot2, #trikot3. You need to define display: inline-block; for those containers:

```
#trikot1, #trikot2, #trikot3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```